# How can I allow two or more users to add records on my database simultaneously?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am a newbie in database and it is not my course but I like programming.

I have created a simple database where customer will use this to request samples.

My problem is I can't make the database work when two users are adding new records.

Here are my code when they click the Send button.

```
        DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , _
        "michael.manalo@yahoo.com;", _
        , , _
        "Sample Request from " & [Location], "Dear RCM Project Engineering, " & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        "I would like to request for samples to be shipped to:" & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        [Contact] & Chr$(13) & [Shipping Address] & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        "Details of my request were recorded in SRN " _
        & [SRN] & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        "The customer is requesting for:" & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY1] & " " & [PN1] & ", " & [Des1] & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY2] & " " & [PN2] & ", " & [Des2] & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY3] & " " & [PN3] & ", " & [Des3] & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY4] & " " & [PN4] & ", " & [Des4] & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY5] & " " & [PN5] & ", " & [Des5] & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY6] & " " & [PN6] & ", " & [Des6] & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY7] & " " & [PN7] & ", " & [Des7] & Chr$(13) & _
        [QTY8] & " " & [PN8] & ", " & [Des8] & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        "Please note of the following: " & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        [Remarks] & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        "Expected Delivery Date is on: " & [Requested Delivery Date] & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
        "Thank You!" & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & Form_Choose.user & Chr$(13) & [Position]

        DoCmd.Save acForm, "Sample_Requisition"

        [Requestor] = Form_Choose.user
```

The [Requestor] field is required and I locked them for editing by users because I wanted the customer to successfully email their request before the record can be saved. If they successfully emailed their request, the current user (from Choose form) will be automatically recorded in the requestor field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading.

[Best Practices When Using Microsoft Office Access 2003 in a Multi-user Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167840%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

[Fundamentals of Relational Database Design, Paul Litwin, 2003](http://r937.com/relational.html)

The fact that you have an array of controls (QTY1,QTY2...) suggests that the database design needs work.